# ROR query order by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of rails relationships.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sites
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :Customer
end
```

I want to be able to get a list of sites ordered by the long-name field of the customer and then the long-name field of the site, I want to use the list in a select element on a page, where the individual options will look like this.

Ordered first by the Customer, and then the Sites for that Customer. I do not want to see Customers that have no sites.

- Ball State University - Student Union Building
- Boise State University - Administration
- Boise State University - Student Union Building

I cannot figure out how to build my Site.find statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with somethig like this:

```
@sites = Site.find(:all, :joins => :customer, :order => "customers.long_name, sites.long_name")
```

And then,

```
@sites.each { |s| "#{s.customer.long_name} - #{s.long_name}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
Site.all(:include => :customer, :order => "customers.name, sites.name")
```